# Silverlight Prism 4.0 Active Aware Alternative

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, prism

Is it possible to implement something like the IActiveAware interface in prism where I track whether the User Control is visible or not.(Visually)

IActiveAware does not work in all scenarios especially when used within sub regions.

Eg.  Region A contains a view 1 with Region B with a view 2. When Region A's is navigated to view 3, view 1 IActiveAware's isActive is changed to false, but not the the view 2's IActiveAware, it is still active in memory even when view three is shown.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have included an interface that is based on the Loaded/Unloaded event to track the Visibility of the view on the screen.  This works for now.